# How to check the connection to remote server with a digital certificate (client authentication)

Tags: linux, authentication, ssl-certificate, command-line-interface

I got a digital certificate with extensions for server and client authentication and a private key.

Now I want to connect to a remote server (REST web services) which should accept my requests because of my certificate. As a first step I want to check if this connection will work. The remote server is not under my control.

I have this REST URL https://host.test.com/REST/admin/user/1212/ and I need to do the request with the certificate. So how can I do this through command line (Linux system)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curl or wget.

```
curl --cert <your cert>
```

or

```
wget --certificate=<yourt cert>
```

THe certificate (of course with priv key) needs to be located in a p12 file. You can specify the passphrase of this file.

Comment: I works with ``wget --certificate ./myCert.pem --private-key ./myKey.pem "https://host.test.com/REST/admin/user/1212/"``. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use *openssl s_client* to inspect the certificate for validity.

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.com -CApath /usr/share/ca-certificates
```

This gives me:

```
[mark@pericles ~]$ openssl s_client -connect www.google.de:443 -CApath /usr/share/ca-certificates/
CONNECTED(00000004)
depth=3 C = US, O = Equifax, OU = Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Inc, CN = Google Internet Authority G2
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc, CN = google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
<snip>
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

The *-CApath* parameter point to the CA certificates to validate against. I'm on Arch Linux, hence these are in /usr/share/ca-certificates.

This is extremely handy when debugging certificates you rolled out, but equally useful, when you don't have control over the other side.

To use a client certificate add the following to the *s_client* command line:

```
-cert xxx.pem -key xxx.pem
```

Here xxx.pem contains both the client certificate and the key. You simply pass it to both options.

Comment: I used it this way ``openssl s_client -connect host.test.com:443 -cert myCert.pem -key myKey.pem``, but this only test the connection to the server, not the REST service. With this command, I get a timeout. I have only one certificate, no Root-CA or Intermediate.

Comment: Can you post the initial output of the command? Timeout sounds a lot like there's a network filter in place. Obviously you can speak HTTP over the secured connection right in the console. If the SSL connect works you can do `GET /REST/admin/user/1212/ HTTP/1.1\nHost: host.test.com\n` where the `\n` denotes a newline (simply hit return).